# React Изменение элемента активной ссылки?

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите, пожалуйста, иметься вот такой Реакт компонент меню

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'

import "./menu.scss"

import icon_work from './../Components/images/menu/work.png';
import icon_workBig from './../Components/images/menu/work_big.png';
import icon_bonuses from './../Components/images/menu/bonuses.png';
import icon_bonusesBig from './../Components/images/menu/bonuses_big.png';

import icon_lobby from './../Components/images/menu/lobby.png';
import icon_lobbyBig from './../Components/images/menu/lobby_big.png';

import icon_rating from './../Components/images/menu/rating.png';
import icon_ratingBig from './../Components/images/menu/rating_big.png';

import icon_tournament from './../Components/images/menu/tournament.png';
import icon_tournamentBig from './../Components/images/menu/tournament_big.png';


function Menu(props) {

    const {} = props;


    return (
        <nav className="menu">
            <Router>
            <ul className="menu_list">
                <li className="menu_item">
                    <NavLink className="menu_link" to="/work/">
                        <img className="menu_img" src={icon_work} alt="Работа"/>
                        <p className="menu_name">Работа</p>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="menu_item">
                    <NavLink className="menu_link" to="/bonuses/">
                        <img className="menu_img" src={icon_bonuses} alt="Бонусы"/>
                        <p className="menu_name">Бонусы</p>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="menu_item">
                    <NavLink className="menu_link" exact to="/">
                        <img className="menu_img" src={icon_lobbyBig} alt="Лобби"/>
                        <p className="menu_name">Лобби</p>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="menu_item">
                    <NavLink className="menu_link" to="/tournaments/">
                        <img className="menu_img" src={icon_tournament} alt="Турниры"/>
                        <p className="menu_name">Турниры</p>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="menu_item">
                    <NavLink className="menu_link" to="/rating/">
                        <img className="menu_img" src={icon_rating} alt="Рейтинг"/>
                        <p className="menu_name">Рейтинг</p>
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </Router>
        </nav>
    )
}


export default Menu
```

Как реализовать так, что по нажатию на активную ссылку у меня не только для ссылки добавлялся активный класс, но и иконка меню менялась на icon_...Big ?   На пример по нажатию на ссылку `Бонусы  src={icon_bonuses} переходило в src={icon_bonusesBig}` ну а той ссылке у которой была большая иконка, она обратна становилась маленькой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой и быстрый способ: поместите в элемент меню несколько иконок, без класса `.active` показывайте одну, а когда на элементе есть класс `.active` – другую. Манипулировать отображением картинок можно через свойство `display: none`.

Второй вариант – изначально грузить большую картинку, но манипулировать её размером через свойство `transform: scale`.

P.S. В целом в 2021 году вместо банального использования `img` в качестве картинок обратите внимание на иконочные шрифты или SVG-спрайты.

Comment: Наверное стоит дополнить что иконки активного и не активного состояния совершенно разные (не только по размерам)

Comment: ИМХО Использование иконочных шрифтов и SVG спрайтов раздувает проект что не очень хорошо, потом получаеться что на страницах где они не востребованы, они тоже подтягиваются

Comment: @BlackStar1991 тогда первый варинт используйте.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 вы можете вебпаком собрать свой иконочный шрифт только с теми иконками, которые вам нужны. Вот к примеру у меня иконочный шрифт в формате woff2 из 37 иконок весит 7кб. ИМХО, это меньше, чем одна ваша иконка.